# Always show the selected item, when a edittext has focus inside a listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a dialog that contains a listview, this listview contains edittext boxes.

The problem is that when the edittext box is selected the softkeyboard will cover it up.

So far  i have tried with limited success calling this in the dialogs initialisation:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

What happens with this is whenever I select an edittext the dialog resizes exactly how I want but it also unfocuses the edittext at the same time. A similar outcome occurs when using `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` resetting the pan when the edittext is reselected.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add it to manifest,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

Comment: my dialog doesn't derive from activity so there is no entry for it in the manifest

Comment: this still has the same effect as setting it programmatically, once the edittext has focus it resets the pan or resize of the dialog

Comment: I will eventually but the code is already rather bloated so i need to separate it.



I just tried setting the dimension explicitly with the code below called from a focus listen on the edittext. but the problem is that any resize operation on the window/dialog unfocuses the edittext even if i call the edittext to regain focus afterwards


int width = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth(); 
  if(dialogheight == 0){
   dialogheight=this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
  }else{
   dialogheight = dialogheight + resize;
  }  
  this.getWindow().setLayout(width, dialogheight);

Comment: i've decided to use a scrollview with a table layout, which i'm adding and inflating the list view items inside programmatically instead of a listview